# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 't.forEach') Firebase React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

My application was working normally, to my surprise, after some update, the system stopped working.
The moment the app tries to query some data in the database, it displays the error below.

```
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 't.forEach'), stack:
<unknown>@736:531
<unknown>@787:4798
value@47:1279
<unknown>@758:1112
value@47:1279
<unknown>@768:1597
value@47:1279
value@27:3544
<unknown>@27:840
value@27:2798
value@27:812
value@-1

    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:79)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Following code for analysis, noting that there was no change, I did several searches but without success.

Code *****

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Container, Title, Form, Input, Submit, List, Name, Header, BackButton,
  ContainerList, Stats, Buttons, Conferencia, NameList, Edit, EditName,
} from './styles';
import { Image, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
Icon.loadFont();
import logoImg from '../../assets/darmand.png';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

export default function Lists() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [lists, setLists] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = useState([]);

  function navigateToListProduts(list, name, user, date) {
    navigation.navigate('ListProducts', { list, name, user, date });
  }

  function navigateToProdutsAdd() {
    navigation.navigate('ListAdd');
  }

  //COMO CONSULTAR OS DADOS DE UMA SUBCOLEÇÃO. EXEMPLO ABAIXO:

  //.collection('Lists').doc('LOJA-MAO1').collection('LOJA-MAO1')
  useEffect(() => {


    const subscriber = firestore()
      .collection('Lists')
      .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        const lists = [];


        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
          lists.push({
            ...documentSnapshot.data(),
            key: documentSnapshot.id,
          });
        });
        

        setLists(lists);
        setLoading(false);
      });

      setFilteredList(
        lists.filter(list => {
          return list.name.includes(search)
        })
      )

    // Unsubscribe from events when no longer in use
    return () => subscriber();
  }, [search, lists]);

  if (loading) {
    return <ActivityIndicator />
  }
```

Comment: What did you update ?

Comment: I found the reason for the error.
Firebase permissions had been loosened.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your firestore rules

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```